# Meaning of assembly instructions

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu-assembler

I am working my way through [http://www.amazon.com/Assembly-Language-Step-Step-Programming/dp/0470497025](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470497025).

Currently, I'm trying to move some of the code around so that I can compile with GAS, instead of NASM (the book's default compiler), and I'm having trouble understanding what some of it means.

This is my source code of confusion

```
EatMsg: db *Eat at Joe's!* , 10

EatLen: equ $-EatMst
```

(it's in .section .data)

how would I rewrite it to work with GAS?

Comment: Your value for `EatMsg: db` needs to be in quotes (`'`)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'd have to study the documentation of `nasm` to see what the construct is doing, then read the `gas` manual on how to achieve the equivalent thing.

In this case, `db` is defining some data bytes, and the `equ` defines an alias for the length, using `$` for the current address. The code for `gas` is:

```
EatMsg:
    .ascii "*Eat at Joe's*"
    .byte 10
.equ EatLen, . - EatMsg
```

You could also incorporate the `10` (which is the ascii code of line feed) as `\n` into the string.

The simplest solution would be to simply install `nasm`, of course.

Comment: Or if you really like AT&T, try Jonathan Bartlett's "Programming From The Ground Up".